# How to find a nearest point to a given query line from a set of points in O(log n) time with out using duality concept?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Assume that we have been given a set S of n points and an arbitrary query line l. Do some preprocessing (other than duality) so that we can answer the nearest (closest) point (of S) to l in O(log n) time (no restriction on space).

Comment: Dear Vikram, we use Kd-tree for range search in d-dimensional space. Kd-tree is irrelevant to  my question. Thanks....

Comment: By query line u mean y = mx + c  ?

Comment: Could you please explain how it can be or at least some idea. As for my knowledge we can use kd-tree to find the point that is nearest to a given input point. In my case query line (y = mx + c) is given.

Comment: What is a query line?

Comment: @Lajos some line of the form y = mx + c given as input

Comment: What do you mean with duality in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You say "no restriction on space", which implies no restriction on preprocessing time.

Consider the sorted abscissas of the sites after rotation by an arbitrary angle: the site closest to a vertical line is found by dichotomy after `Lg(N)` comparisons.

Now consider the continuous set of rotations: you can partition it in angle ranges such that the order of the sorted abscissas does not change.

So you will find all limiting angles by taking the sites in pairs, and store the angle value as well as the corresponding ordering of the rotated abscissas.

For a query, find the enclosing angle interval by a first binary search (among O(N²) angles), then the closest site by a search on the rotated abscissas (binary search among O(N) abscissas).

Done the straightforward way, this will require O(N³) storage.

Given that the ordering permutations for two consecutive angles just differ by a single swap, it is not unthinkable that O(N²) storage can be achieved by a suitable data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Distance from line for point `(xi,yi)` is `d = |yi-mxi-c|/sqrt(1+m^2)`.

We need to minimize `f(x,y) = (y-mx-c)^2`

These are quadratic equations in `(m,c)` .

**Satisfying conditions :-**

```
F(xi,yi) <= F(x1,y1),F(x2,y2)..
```

Suppose you get a solver for this then you would get intervals of `(m,c)` where the conditions are satisfied.

You can use interval tree to search interval and point where a line `(m,c)` lies .

Comment: Intervals don't have 'nice' shape and for one point there are more intervals for which it is the nearest point.

Comment: @Ante Whatever be the shape the interval tree can arrange them such that they are searchable in O(logN), though there is no guarentee how many intervals are there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the line which goes through `I` and is perpendicular to the line. Then solve the pair of equation of the two lines to get the intersection. That is the closest point to `I` from the initial line, but it is not necessarily in `S`. Let's call the intersection `I'`. If your elements in `S` are ordered by `x`, then you can simply do a binary search to get the closest `x` in `S` to `I'.x` and return the point having that `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to phrase it directly in terms of duality, but the key observation is that for two points, the boundary between lines closer to one point than the other point are the set of lines that satisfy certain inequalities on the slope and intercept of the line. So if you use these inequalities, then in a sense you are treating the line as a "point" (a pair of numbers that satisfy certain inequalities to find the nearest point) no matter what you do. It seems like the only other option is to do some preprocessing so you can quickly find the closest projection of your points onto an arbitrary given line (e.g. by computing a small number of projections and eliminating the rest from consideration), but that seems hard to make run in guaranteed O(log n) time per query line.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

Preprocess with a rotating sweep line through angles 0 to pi by projecting all the points onto that line and recording the sweep line angle theta and parameters for the projected points, doing this once for each time two points are coincident ie "cross over each other". By "parameters" I mean pick any fixed origin A and record (p - A) dot [cos theta, sin theta] for all p. There will be O(n^2) of these scan line records, so they can be searched by angle in O(log n) time. Given a query line Q, use binary search to find the two recorded sweep lines that bracket Q' s perpendicular in angle. The recorded projections have the same ordering of points as the ordering of points projected on Q's perpendicular.  Now find the parameter for point R that is the projection of Q onto its own perpendicular through A. Use one more binary search in the bracketing sweep lines to find the point closest to B. This is the closest point to Q.